# std::mutex and std::condition_variable construction overhead vs heap allocation

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, mutex, condition-variable

I have a `task` class that I need to be movable. I have around 10-15 tasks that are contained in a `task_storage` parent class. Inside `task::execute()` I need to wait for an atomic variable to reach zero:

```
void task::execute()
{
    for_subtasks([this]
        {
            thread_pool.post([this]
                {
                    this->do_work();

                    // Atomic counter.
                    --(this->_remaining_subtasks);
                });
        });

    // wait for `_remaining_subtasks == 0`
}
```

I have thought of three alternatives to wait for `_remaining_subtasks == 0` while keeping `task` movable:

1. Use a `while(...){ sleep(1); }` busy waiting loop.
2. Construct and use an `std::mutex` and an `std::condition_variable` inside the function.

   ```
   void task::execute()
   {
       std::mutex m;
       std::condition_variable cv;

       for_subtasks(/* ... */);

       std::unique_lock<std::mutex> l(m);
       cv.wait(l, [this]{ return this->_remaining_subtasks == 0; });
   }
   ```
3. Store   an `std::unique_ptr<std::mutex>` and an `std::unique_ptr<std::condition_variable>` inside `task` as fields. This would allow `task` to be movable, but also introduce indirection to access the synchronization primitives.

   ```
   void task::execute()
   {
       for_subtasks(/* ... */);

       std::unique_lock<std::mutex> l(*this->_m);
       this->_cv.wait(l, [this]{ return this->_remaining_subtasks == 0; });
   }
   ```

I don't intend on using busy waiting. I tried profiling the fastest solution between 2 and 3 but could not get any meaningful result.

**Is the construction overhead for `std::mutex` and `std::condition_variable` significant?** Or would the heap allocations/accesses be slower?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the construction overhead for std::mutex and std::condition_variable significant? Or would the heap allocations/accesses be slower?

In both cases constructors must be invoked. The difference is where the memory is allocated: static storage, stack or heap. Heap allocation is the slowest.

On Linux and POSIX compatible systems, `std::mutex` and `std::condition_variable` are thin wrappers over POSIX `pthread_mutex_t` and `pthread_cond_t` structures. Initializing these structures involves setting member variables of fundamental types and no calls. In other words, the construction is cheap.